# Not understanding division in Birthday Paradox

Tags: probability, arithmetic

I am reading Scientific American's explanation for birthday paradox [here](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/bring-science-home-probability-birthday-paradox/)

I understand everything in the article up to

> Every one of the 253 combinations has the same odds, 99.726027
>   percent, of not being a match. If you multiply 99.726027 percent by
>   99.726027 253 times, or calculate (364/365)253, you'll find there's a 49.952 percent chance that all 253 comparisons contain no matches.

When I compute $364/365 \times 253$, the answer is $252.306$

Why is the article saying it is $49.952%$?

Comment: It is not saying multiply by $253$ but rather **raise to the power of** $253$.  $(\frac{364}{365})^{253}=\underbrace{ \frac{364}{365}\cdot \frac{364}{365}\cdots \frac{364}{365}}_{253~\text{number of times}}$

Comment: To be fair, there's a typo in the expression in the article as well — the 253 is on the same baseline as the fraction, rather than raised as an exponent should be.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before you post them. (division-algebras) tag is completely irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @Wojowu: I agree, and I replaced the tag with a more appropriate one. You can do the same actually. If only newbies would read [the tag wikis](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/division-algebras/info).... That'll be the day.

Comment: That article's calculation isn't correct, I don't think. If person A and B don't share the same birthday, and person A and C don't share the same birthday, it is less probable that person B and C don't share the same birthday than if we knew nothing. That is, the events aren't independent. It's an overestimate of the probability that no birthdays are shared, though, and it's not a bad approximation, especially for less people.

Comment: One can write $364/365\times 253$, coded as 364/365\times 253, or $364/365\cdot 253$, coded as 364/365\cdot253.  Using an asterisk, as in $364/365*253$, is a workaround for occasions when one is limited to the characters on the keyboard. I changed it. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Multiplying 99.726027 percent by 99.726027 percent 253 times" means 
$$(0.99726027)^{253} \approx 0.49952.$$

Comment: Scanning the Sci Am article quickly, I get the impression that the confusion between multiplier and exponent originates with OP.

Answer (score 3):

Comment: This may be a useful intuitive argument to convince skeptics that the probability is less than half. Especially so, if the skeptic is thinking he/she is unlikely to be involved in a birthday match. However, more precisely, $P(\text{No match}) = \prod_{i=0}^{24}(1 - \frac{i}{365}) = 0.4927,$ assuming that 23 subjects are sampled at random from among 365 equally likely birthdays. The Scientific American
argument does not deal appropriately with the possibility of three
or more people with the same birthdays.

Another faulty line is thinking is that there can be no match with one person and that it would require 366 subjects to insure a match. Then to think that the relationship between number of subjects and a match must be roughly linear for 0 to 365. The distinctly nonlinear relationship is shown in the figure below (from R).

```
 n = 1:60; p  = numeric(60)
 for (i in n) {q = prod(1 - (0:(i-1))/365)
   p[i] = 1 - q}
 plot(n, p, pch=19, ylab="P(Match)")
 p[60]
 ## 0.9941227
```

[image]

Comment: The article isn't correct, but it's not too far off. It would generalize to say that the probability of no matches existing is $\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{\frac{n^2+n}2}$. This probability is too high, as it essentially puts $\left(1-\frac{1}{365}\right)^n$ where $\left(1-\frac{n}{365}\right)$ should be. Obviously, it gives a positive probability that 366 people have no shared birthdays, which is wrong, but for lower numbers, it works out better.